# Getting exit code of shell execution inside define

Tags: shell, makefile

I have something like this in my makefile:

```
exit_code := $(shell some_script.py; echo $$?)
ifneq ($(exit_code),0)
    $(error Error occured)
endif
```

and it works properly - the `echo $$?` returns exit code of python script

I need to put that code into define like that:

```
define run-python-script
    exit_code := $(shell some_script.py; echo $$?)
    ifneq ($(exit_code),0)
        $(error Error occured)
    endif
endef
$(call run-python-script)
```

but then `exit_code` does not contain the exit code. And `$(error Error occured)` is always executed.

How to make work the version with define?

Comment: This seems bass-ackwards. If you run the Python script in a recipe, the default behavior of Make is already to abort on error.

Comment: @tripleee, what's more, OP runs the script every time the Makefile is parsed and during the parsing. There are use-cases for that, but I still get the feeling OP asked wrong question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to put that code into define like that:

1. The `if()`/`endif` are processed and evaluated when the `Makefile` is parsed. You can't use them inside a variable definition.
2. The `exit_code := ...` in first snippet is a definition of a `make` variable, while in the second it is just a string, part of the `make`'s variable called `run-python-script`.

You can try this (your script is replaced with `false` for test purposes):

```
eq = $(and $(findstring $(1),$(2)),$(findstring $(2),$(1)))
the-command = false; echo $$?
run-python-script = $(if $(call eq,0,$(shell $(the-command))),,$(error Error occured))
$(run-python-script)
```

(The `$(call)` is redundant in that case.)